# git - Merge branch from remoteRepo to local branch

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, gitlab

I've been googling for hours, trying to find the way.

I got a repo on gitlab, wish to merge one from github into a branch of mine at my gitlab repo. A way of comitting a merge, or likewise

example:

> Merge branch 'Sarah' of https://github.com/repo/server into myServer

where myserver is my branch, sarah is the links branch and the link is a repo

Thank you in advance.
PS. I'm noob in this subject, be userfriendly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a remote to your Git Lab repo.

```
git remote add gitlab https://gitlab.com/user/repo.git
git fetch gitlab
```

Add a remote to Git Hub

```
git remote add github https://github.com/user/repo.git
git fetch github
```

Checkout a new `temp` branch to merge based on `myServer`

```
git checkout -b temp gitlab/myServer
```

Merge `Sarah` and resolve conflicts, etc.

```
git merge github/Sarah
```

Now you're free to do whatever you'd like with your `temp` branch. Like push it to Git Lab.

```
git push gitlab temp
```

Or if you love it, then you could "overwrite" your `myServer` branch by forcing the branch name to point to this commit.

```
git branch -f myServer
```

And then push that to Git Lab (you may need to force depending on context)

```
git push gitlab myServer
```

Comment: fatal: pathspec 'remote' did not match any files

:S
c:\files\myRepo  ?

Comment: @Sarah whoops, sorry that was a typo. Should have been `git remote add ...`

Comment: Most likely the local repo was cloned from either GitHub or GitLab. This means that technically you do not have to add both remotes because one of them is already `origin`. Of course, adding the remotes with these specific names makes it much more clear which is which.

Comment: A reasonable alternative to `git branch -f myServer` is `git checkout myServer` then `git merge temp`.